# How to disable caching only on the wordpress homepage

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, caching

On Wordpress, I would like to set the browser cache expiration on the “**index.html**” homepage to “**0**“.

And the rest of the html files in **1 week**.

I tried to do it via **htaccess** using the code below

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
# Enable expirations
ExpiresActive On 
# Default directive
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"

ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 1 week"
    <FilesMatch "^(index\.html)$">
        ExpiresActive On
        ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 0 seconds"
        Header append Cache-Control "public"
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

But only a week’s setup works:

```
ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 1 week"
```

This setting inside “FilesMatch” is completely ignored.

```
ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 0 seconds"
```

However, when I try to disable the caching of the **styles.css** file instead of **index.html**, the code works.

It seems to be something related to the html type when it is **inside** “FilesMatch”

**Can anyone help me with this, please?**

Answer (score 1):

WordPress doesn't use `index.html`.  It uses `index.php`  You can change your match like this:

```
<FilesMatch "^(index\.[a-z0-9]+)?$">
```

- `[a-z0-9]+)?` matches any extension on the index file
- Adding the `?` makes the index file optional so that the rule might match the home page when the index file is implied rather than present in the URL.

Answer (score -1):

if you are using WPRocket plugin for cache handling then it provide option to set value in particular page also

Comment: HI @Janki - Ok, but see that I mean the cache on the browser side, not the one made on the server.
Does WPRocket allow to disable the caching of a specific page in the BROWSER? for example, the HOME page?
I searched for WP Rocket in the Wordpress plugins nothing was found. can you let me know the link? is a paid plugin?